# Proof check: commutation of Galois automorphisms and complex conjugation in CM-fields

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a Galois CM-field with $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})=:G$ and $J_\mathbb{C}$ be the complex conjugation. Since $K$ is a CM-field one can show, that $$J:=\phi^{-1}\circ J_\mathbb{C}\circ \phi=\psi^{-1}\circ J_\mathbb{C}\circ \psi$$ for all embeddings $\phi,\psi$. These embeddings are the Galois automorphisms. So the equation holds for all $\phi,\psi\in G$. Therefore it also needs to work with the identity $id$:$$J=\phi^{-1}\circ J_\mathbb{C}\circ \phi=id^{-1}\circ J_\mathbb{C}\circ id=J_\mathbb{C},$$  which is equivalent to $$J_\mathbb{C}\circ\phi=\phi\circ J_\mathbb{C}.$$ It follows $$J\circ\phi=\phi\circ J,$$ what I wanted to show.

Was I allowed to use the "trick" with the identity? Is the proof right?

Comment: Absolutely. But be careful  because an embedding is a map $K\to \mathbb C$, while a Galois automorphism is a map $K\to K$. Thus, the two concepts are slightly different, as you are not allowed to consider the inverse of an embedding. In your proof, $\phi$ and $\psi$ are automorphisms and not embeddings.